# getting dynamic data from views to javascript

Tags: python, django, django-templates

Just like we can set a context variable for the default users in a django template, `var user = "{{request.user}}"` How do I do the same thing for a custom Model?

When I try using `var text = "{{ news }}";` it displays random letters instead of the objects one by one

let's say there are three objects associated with News model:

```
object1 = "this is test one"
object2 = "this is test two"
object3 = "this is test three"
```

model

```
class News(models.Model):
    news_today = models.CharField(max_length=80, null=True, blank=True)
```

views

```
def test(request):
    news = News.objects.all()
    context = {"news ": news}
```

template

```
<script>

    var text = "{{request.news}}";

</script>
```

js [trying to achieve showcasing of one sentence at a time from those three objects]

```
var counter = 0;
var elem = document.getElementById("changeText");
var inst = setInterval(change, 5000);

function change() {
  elem.innerHTML = text[counter];
  counter++;
  if (counter >= text.length) {
    counter = 0;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get each news model's text in javascript you'll need to use template tags to loop through each object and assign their text to a new variable

```
<script>

    {% for object in news %}
       var news{{ object.id }} = "{{ object.news_today }}"
    {% endfor %}

</script>
```

Here, for each object, a new variable is created named news0, news1, news2, etc... and that variable contains its corresponding text.

```
<script>

    var news = []
    {% for object in news %}
        news.append("{{ object.news_today }}")
    {% endfor %}

</script>
```

Here, a list is created with each news text so depending on your use case you can choose to use whichever one you want.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to assign a django model queryset to a simple var in JS, that is a bad idea, you need to be more concise, if you need a list of texts you can loop the queryset and build a list of texts:

```
var text = [];
{% for n in news %}
    text.push("{{n.news_today}}");
{% endfor %}
// do what ever you want with your list of news texts
```